# How to create a nested object from req.query?

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I am trying to create an object that will be used to post to an Event Grid. There are top-level properties such as **EventType**, **Subject**, **DataVersion**, and **EventTime**. However, I would like anything else provided to req.query to be added as a child to the data property. Currently, the below code only adds the last item in `req.query` vs keep adding/appending to it.

```
let parms = req.query;

for (var i in parms) {
  let myKey = i;
  let myValue = req.query[i];

  switch (i) {
    case 'eventtype':
      event[0].eventtype = myValue;
      break;

    case 'subject':
      event[0].subject = myValue;
      break;

    default:
      event[0].data = { [myKey]: myValue };
      break;
  }
}
```

Output

```
eventTime: 2019-03-23T13:47:26.069Z,
dataVersion: '2.0',
eventtype: 'build',
subject: 'build' },
data: { color: 'red' } ]
```

Desired Outcome

```
eventTime: 2019-03-23T13:47:26.069Z,
dataVersion: '2.0',
eventtype: 'build',
subject: 'build' },
data: { color: red, power: on }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `data` as a object, then append key and value to the `data`.

```
let parms = req.query;

for (var i in parms) {

    let myKey = i;
    let myValue = req.query[i];

    switch (i) {

        case "eventtype":
            event[0].eventtype = myValue;
            break;

        case "subject":
            event[0].subject = myValue;
            break;

        default:
            if (event[0].data) {
                event[0].data[myKey] = myValue;
            } else {
                event[0].data = { [myKey]: myValue }
            }
            break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which will iterate over own properties of the object and the new property which is necessary.

```
let parms = req.query;

for (var i in parms) {

  let myKey = i;
  let myValue = req.query[i];

  switch (i) {

    case "eventtype":
      event[0].eventtype = myValue;
      break;

    case "subject":
      event[0].subject = myValue;
      break;

    default:
      event[0].data = Object.assign(event[0].data, { myKey: myValue }); 
      break;
  }
};
```